# How do I replace mouseover with mousemove?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, css

Trying to change a website to work with iphone. With the original code I move the mouse over "hotspots" in order. However, I'm not able to use the mouseover with the iphone and mousemove doesn't seem to work either. This is the specific code:

```
            $(this).animate({
                left: pos.x,
                top: pos.y
            }, 700);
        }).mousemove(function() {
            onclick = "void(0)"
            var index = parseInt($(this).text());
            if (passed != index - 1) {
                return;
            }
```

Comment: Too little code to work with. I'm uncertain how the iphone reacts with mousemove, but dragging your thumb over the display should work the same. You're saying it doesn't ?

Comment: Expect all hover and most cursor movement related events (in, on, over, out, down, up, etc.) not to work on touch interfaces. If you start re-programming gestures so that touch works like mouseover, how do you do a click? Very quickly users have a UI they can't understand. Start using UI features that don't need animation or user prompting to say "click me" or show data.

Comment: Khez - Dragging my finger over the display causes nothing to happen. Dragging my mouse over the display causes the spots to indicate they have been hit.

Answer (score 1):

On mobile WebKit (iPhone, Android, others) browsers, look for touchstart, touchend, and touchmove events.

Comment: Khez - Dragging my finger over the display causes nothing to happen. Dragging my mouse over the display causes the spots to indicate they have been hit.

Answer (score 0):

An explanation of javascript events on iPhone : [touching-and-gesturing-on-the-iphone](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/10/touching-and-gesturing-on-the-iphone/)